# How Can i target one of my pictureboxes created on runtime? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, runtime, minesweeper

So basically, i have successfully randomized certain pictureboxes in a grid to contain mines, and show that mine, and for testing purposes, those mines are currently showing. What do you think I need to do to be able to say:

> If, you click this box and mine = 1 (there's a mine), then you lose. 
>   Else, keep going.

simple enough, but i want to apply this to all boxes, no matter how big the grid is. (ZonesX * Zones Y)

The furthest I have gotten is being about to pop up a MsgBox() when anyone of them is clicked.

This is all created on runtime. Heres my code.

```
Public Class Form1
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Dim images(8) As Image 'declares image array

Dim zonesY As Integer = 10
Dim zonesX As Integer = 10

Dim Guy As Object
Dim pbxNewZone As PictureBox = DirectCast(Guy, PictureBox)  'declares pbxNewZone as a picturebox variable

Dim generator As New Random

Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    images(0) = Image.FromFile("blank.png")
    images(1) = Image.FromFile("1.png")
    images(2) = Image.FromFile("2.png")
    images(3) = Image.FromFile("3.png")
    images(4) = Image.FromFile("4.png")
    images(5) = Image.FromFile("5.png")
    images(6) = Image.FromFile("clear.png")
    images(7) = Image.FromFile("hit.png")
    images(8) = Image.FromFile("mine.png")

    Dim x As Integer  'declares x as an integer variable
    Dim y As Integer  'declares y as an integer variable
    Me.SuspendLayout()  'suspends creation of layout

    For y = 1 To zonesY 'starts a For loop (1 to zonesY number of loops)
        For x = 1 To zonesX  'starts a For loop (1 to zonesX number of loops)
            Dim zonesize1 As Integer
            Dim zonesize2 As Integer

            pbxNewZone = New PictureBox

            Dim blockStatus As Integer
            Dim allZones As Integer
            allZones = zonesX * zonesY
            blockStatus = generator.Next(0, allZones)

            pbxNewZone.Name = y & ", " & x
            If blockStatus < (allZones / 10) Then
                pbxNewZone.Tag = True
                If pbxNewZone.Tag = True Then
                    pbxNewZone.Image = images(8)
                End If
            Else
                pbxNewZone.Tag = False
                If pbxNewZone.Tag = False Then
                    pbxNewZone.Image = images(0)
                End If
            End If
            pbxNewZone.Height = 16
            pbxNewZone.Width = 16
            pbxNewZone.Tag = 0
            zonesize1 = pbxNewZone.Height 'sets out all of the boxes on the form.
            zonesize2 = pbxNewZone.Width
            pbxNewZone.Left = ((x - 1) * zonesize1 + 15)
            pbxNewZone.Top = ((y - 1) * zonesize2 + 15)
            Me.Controls.Add(pbxNewZone)
            '  Wire this control up to an appropriate event handler
            AddHandler pbxNewZone.Click, AddressOf pbxNewZoneClicked

        Next
    Next
    Me.Height = (pbxNewZone.Height * zonesY + 63)  'sets the height of fmmGame
    Me.Width = (pbxNewZone.Width * zonesX + 40)  'sets the width of frmGame

End Sub

Private Sub pbxNewZoneClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim pbTag As Boolean = DirectCast(sender, Boolean)

        If pb.Tag = True Then
            pb.Image = images(7) 'Hit Image
        Else
            pb.Image = images(6) 'Clear Image
        End If

    MsgBox(pb.Tag)

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to do it would be to use the `Tag` element of the `PictureBox` to keep track of whether there is a mine or not (or any of your other conditions).

```
pbxnewzone.Tag = 1   'can assign tags to all of your pictureboxes in a loop or at random if need be
```

Then, access the `Tag` property by casting the `sender` argument of your `pbxNewZoneClicked` method back to a `PictureBox`:

```
Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
If (pb.Tag = 1) Then
    'change game accordingly
End If
```

Comment: Got it. Now i have it checking for tag = 1 or 0, and it assigns the mine image randomly, but lower in the code, as you suggested I have i have it checking for tag on the click of a box. When I say if pb.Tag = 1 it does nothing, and when i have ElseIf pb.Tag = 2 it does nothing (same for = True/False). I only get a result when i use Else, even at that i can only change it to one image, and it does not recognize a mine or a clear. So i have concluded that its not pulling the .Tag element from the loop. How to I spit the .Tag = 1/2 (True/False) out of the loop, and into the Click event for pb?

Comment: Loop:

For y = 1 To zonesY 'starts a For loop and creates grid (1 to zonesY number of loops)
            For x = 1 To zonesX  'starts a For loop (1 to zonesX number of loops)

Comment: I MsgBox(pb.Tag)'d it, its always returning 0. As I see it, DirectCast works as a portal from **Public Sub Form1_Load** to **Private Sub pbxNewZoneClicked**. Do I need to somehow pass the pbxNewZone.Tag through that door/portal?

Comment: There's no portal, it's event driven, so every time the box is clicked it raised that `pbxNewZoneClicked` event.  Whichever box is clicked is implicitly sent into that method as `sender`, but you must cast it back to whichever type of object that it is to access the members and methods.  Assign each box a tag in a loop in the `Load` method.

Comment: I do. And based on whether its True or False (from Random), it assigns a mine.png to the Picturebox. If i MsgBox(pbxNewZone.Tag) it spits out True or False. But if i MsgBox(pb.Tag) after the DirectCast, it always sends 0.

Comment: feel free to copy and paste my code into VB 2010, its all created on runtime, so it would be easy for you to debug. Code is updated.

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAH, i set it back to .Tag = 0 everytime!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, set minePictureBox1.Tag = true then check it on the click event. Or you could set it to 1 or whatever. Tag is an object.

Is that what you're looking for? Just a way to know if it's a mine or not?

Answer (score 1):

I would think one panel for the entire grid would be easier to manage and less resource hungry then a picturebox for each and every cell.

But for your click issue:

```
Private Sub pbxNewZoneClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  With DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    MsgBox(.Name)
  End With
End Sub
```